# SQLite Very Slow ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sqlite

Well i am using SQLite but when i start to execute non queries probably 10k+ commands [.sql file]. I find that it is very slow that it could take up to 10min+ to end adding the info to the database.

Anyway this is my ExecuteNonQuery code.

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql)
{
    var cnn = new SQLiteConnection(_dbConnection);
    cnn.Open();
    var mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn) {CommandText = sql};
    int rowsUpdated = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cnn.Close();
    return rowsUpdated;
}
```

I hope there is a way to just make it take seconds to finish.

Comment: Probably your problem is in your query?

Comment: I doubt that because it is very simple INSERT INTO CMDS from a .sql script

Comment: do you have them wrapped in begin-commit statement?

Comment: One insert statment or 10k?

Comment: i will post how i am using it.

Comment: @Fox32 more than 10k insert statements [FROM A .SQL FILE]

Comment: @JaredHarley Jojoba's solution is actually good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing with SQLite is that you **have** wrap insert-update-delete commands in a transaction otherwise it will be painfully slow. You can either do this with the transaction support built into the .NET Data Provider or since you are reading a .sql file you could make the first line `begin transaction` and the last line `commit transaction`. Either way should work.

If you want to do it in the .sql file then it might look like this.

```
begin transaction;

insert into ...;
update ...;
delete ...;

commit transaction;
```

Or if you do it in code it would look like this.

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql)
{
    var cnn = new SQLiteConnection(_dbConnection);
    cnn.Open();
    var transaction = cnn.BeginTransaction();
    var mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn) {CommandText = sql};
    mycommand.Transaction = transaction;
    int rowsUpdated = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    transaction.Commit();
    cnn.Close();
    return rowsUpdated;
}
```

Comment: You have my code above could you edit your answer with what you are pointing to. Because when i added the begin transaction and comit lines to the .sql file i got SQL Logic error

Comment: i added those lines to the beginning and the ending lines of the .sql file but i find that it does not do anything, otherwise the query is frozen now.

Comment: @RuneS: Hmm...that's odd because that is exactly how I do it and it works fine. What was the error you got back from sqlite the first time?

Comment: When i try both ways with the begin, end transaction when i click the process button and watch the database file it only makes 2kb and then it is frozen i don't know why. [Although without begin and end transaction, it is adding to the file and it is getting bigger constantly.

Comment: @RuneS: Try running the .sql file through using the sqlite3.exe command line. If that doesn't work then you know the problem is likely with your script as opposed to C# code.

Comment: Note : i am trying to add from a .sql file that is full of INSERT INTO cmds, also i am reading it using `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"file.sql");` and then execute the non query using the text returned from the `File.ReadAllText`

Comment: Well it actually works now but still too slow...

Comment: @RuneS: 10K commands should go through pretty quick. What kind of speeds are you seeing now?

Comment: How can i monitor the speed in my code ? i took more than 6 minutes to execute those 10k commands

Comment: @RuneS: Yeah, 6 minutes sounds excessive. Trying running that .sql file through the command line (sqlite3.exe) and see what you get.

Comment: can you tell me the command to run it in sqlite3.exe i really don't have a background with that

Comment: Well my problem is not solved yet, i still facing a very slow data adding from the sql file although i have a begin and commit transaction

Comment: I had the same problem inserting a few thousand rows in a PHP script. It took several minutes. After I wrapped the INSERTs inside a transaction it took no time. Modern SQLite allows multiple value INSERTs, which would be considered a single transaction, but that wasn’t available to me. Thanks.